# How to get the total number of a data with a specific value in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

So I created a list of data and i need to be able to get the total number of data that has a status: 'Open' and display it in the console.log.

```
const approvals = [
  {
    id: 1,
    member: 'Charlie Lubin',
    payPeriod: 'Sun, Jan 15, 2023 - Sat, Jan 21, 2023',
    duration: '45:11:36',
    activity: '0.57',
    status: 'Open',
    submittedOn: '-',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    member: 'Madelyn Baptista',
    payPeriod: 'Sun, Jan 15, 2023 - Sat, Jan 21, 2023',
    duration: '45:11:36',
    activity: '0.71',
    status: 'Open',
    submittedOn: '-',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    member: 'Lincoln Arcand',
    payPeriod: 'Sun, Jan 15, 2023 - Sat, Jan 21, 2023',
    duration: '45:11:36',
    activity: '0.42',
    status: 'Approved',
    submittedOn: '-',
  },
{
    id: 4,
    member: 'Ryan Botosh',
    payPeriod: 'Sun, Jan 15, 2023 - Sat, Jan 21, 2023',
    duration: '-',
    activity: '-',
    status: 'Approved',
    submittedOn: '-',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    member: 'Craig Workman',
    payPeriod: 'Sun, Jan 15, 2023 - Sat, Jan 21, 2023',
    duration: '45:11:36',
    activity: '0.65',
    status: 'Approved',
    submittedOn: '-',
  },
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const approvals = [
  {
    id: 1,
    member: 'Charlie Lubin',
    payPeriod: 'Sun, Jan 15, 2023 - Sat, Jan 21, 2023',
    duration: '45:11:36',
    activity: '0.57',
    status: 'Open',
    submittedOn: '-',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    member: 'Madelyn Baptista',
    payPeriod: 'Sun, Jan 15, 2023 - Sat, Jan 21, 2023',
    duration: '45:11:36',
    activity: '0.71',
    status: 'Open',
    submittedOn: '-',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    member: 'Lincoln Arcand',
    payPeriod: 'Sun, Jan 15, 2023 - Sat, Jan 21, 2023',
    duration: '45:11:36',
    activity: '0.42',
    status: 'Approved',
    submittedOn: '-',
  },
{
    id: 4,
    member: 'Ryan Botosh',
    payPeriod: 'Sun, Jan 15, 2023 - Sat, Jan 21, 2023',
    duration: '-',
    activity: '-',
    status: 'Approved',
    submittedOn: '-',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    member: 'Craig Workman',
    payPeriod: 'Sun, Jan 15, 2023 - Sat, Jan 21, 2023',
    duration: '45:11:36',
    activity: '0.65',
    status: 'Approved',
    submittedOn: '-',
  },
];

console.log(approvals.filter(a => a.status === 'Open').length)
```

Comment: Could you please help with this question >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75539497/how-do-we-overwrite-the-default-values-to-displayed-in-react-mdeditorarea-with

Answer (score 0):

Using the filter method, you can filter your list to return a new list that has only members that pass the specified check.

```
console.log(approvals.filter((approval) => approval.status === 'Open'))
```