# How do we overwrite the default values to displayed in react `MDEditor`area with the data received from database for editing purpose?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my react app during on load, I have default values to display in react `MDEditor`area. So during on click on `Edit` button, how do I pass the edit `data` and `tag` received from database to display in the `MDEditor` area. Since I already have the default `value={blogValue}` and `value={tagValue}` for those fields how can we do this. Could someone please advise ?

CSB link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-sun-ggh9vh?file=/src/App.js

````
    const myDate = "##### 22 Feb 2023";
    const myTags = "###### cypress";
    const myImage = "![](https://picsum.photos/200)";
    const myHeader = "### Main Header text here"; 
    const myPara  = "Best heading added here.The most relevant data added here. Greatest of all time. Print the whole text here. Ideas are always usefull.... ";
    const myCode = "``` const myData = Test ```";
    const [blogList, setBlogList] = useState([]);
    const [editBlogData, setEditBlogData] = useState([]);
    const [tagValue, setTagValue] = React.useState("");
    const [blogValue, setBlogValue] = React.useState(myImage + "\n" + myDate + "\n" + myTags + "\n" + myHeader + "\n" + myPara + "\n" + "\n" + myCode);


    const onSubmit = () => {
    const email = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');
    const fetchData = async () => {
        console.log("Blog typed data::" + blogValue, tagValue , email);
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${appUrl}/service/createblogs`, {email, blogValue, tagValue});
            if (res.data.success) {
                setHelperText("Successfully inserted the blog data !");
                setBlogValue("");
                setTagValue("");
                window.location.reload(true);
            } 
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    fetchData();
}


 const handleBlogEdit = (idx) => {
        console.log("this is the blog id::" + idx); 
        const params = {
            id: idx,
        };
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {            
                const res = await axios.get(`${appUrl}/service/findblogtoedit`, {params});
                setEditBlogData(res.data.blogData); 
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }

return (
        <div id="App">
            <div className='parent'>
                <div className='adminSection'>
                    <h1>Create a new blog</h1>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className="logout">
                            <input type="button" value="Logout" onClick={handleLogout} />
                        </div>

                        <div className='createBlogSection'>

                            <div data-color-mode="dark" className='container'>
                                <MDEditor
                                    className='reactEditorArea'
                                    id="blogdetails"
                                    name="blogdetails"
                                    value={blogValue}
                                    onChange={setBlogValue}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <form>
                            <div className='row'>
                                <div className='tagsName'>
                                    <label>Tags:</label>
                                    <input
                                        type="text"
                                        id="tags"
                                        name="tags"
                                        placeholder="enter tags"
                                        value={tagValue}
                                        onChange={(e) => setTagValue(e.target.value)}     
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>                 
                            <label>
                             <span className="adminSuccessMsg">{helperText}</span>
                            </label>
                            <div className='row'>
                                <div className='submitSection'>
                                    <input type="submit" onClick={onSubmit} className="submitBtn" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='blogListSection'>
                    <h1>Edit blogs</h1>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='editBlogSection'>
                            {
                                blogList.map(({ id, blogdetails, tags, count }) => (
                                    <div className='row'>
                                        <a key={id} href="some_test_url" className='blogitems'>
                                            <pre><span>{tags}</span> {blogdetails &&  blogdetails.length > 15 ? blogdetails.substring(0, 15) + '...' : blogdetails}<span>{count}</span></pre>
                                        </a>
                                        <div className='blogitems edit'>
                                            <button onClick={() => handleBlogEdit(id)}>Edit</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className='blogitems delete'>
                                            <button onClick={() => handleBlogDelete(id)}>Delete</button>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label>
                        <span className="adminDeleteMsg">{helperText}</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
````